# Convert list to deque runtime

Tags: python

What is the cost of converting from a list to a deque in Python? Example:

```
a_deque = deque(range(100))
a_list = list(a_deque)
```

I would imagine this is O(n) because it needs to parse each item of the iterable, but I would like to know if there is something behind the scenes that makes it more efficient. Thanks!

Comment: It's `O(n)` and for exactly the reason you stated. You can't look at each element faster than `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithmically speaking it's O(n) because `list()` function iterates overt the a_deque and appends the items at the end of the list. The whole process of appending and creation of new object will take time too but the main consumer is the iteration here.

Comment: How about for converting a list into a deque?